# Evitar estouro de memória em uma função PHP

Tags: php, buffer

Galera, tô estreando aqui e estou com o seguinte problema:
Criei uma função com uma dica que encontrei aqui mesmo no stackoverflow.

```
function DozenGenerate($game,$dozen) {
    $this->game = $game;
    $this->dozen = $dozen;
    if ($game === 0) {
        return array(array());
    }
    if (count($dozen) === 0) {
        return array();
    }
    if (count($dozen)< $game){
    }
    ob_start();
    $dozen_receive = $dozen[0];
    $dozen_compare = array_slice($dozen,1,count($dozen)-1);
    $dozenI = $this->DozenGenerate($game-1,$dozen_compare);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($dozenI);$i++){
        array_splice($dozenI[$i],0,0,$dozen_receive);
    }
    ob_get_contents();
    $dozenII = $this->DozenGenerate($game,$dozen_compare);
    ob_end_flush();
    return array_merge($dozenI,$dozenII);
    }
```

Daí crio um range e utilizo a função:

```
$range = range(1,24);
$numbers = DozenGenerate(15,$range);
print_r($numbers);
```

Quando gera combinações únicas muito grandes, retorna esse erro que seria natural:

```
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 25165832 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\netboloes\class\folk.php on line 44
```

Queria saber como faço pra fazer o esvaziamento de memória para que a função continue executando, sem retornar essa mensagem e sim a array? Espero que possam me ajudar.

Comment: 1. Você pode alterar a quantidade de memória no php.ini  2. Você pode declarar no inicio do código  ini_set('memory_limit','16M');  isso seria uma saída paliativa... ou ini_set('memory_limit','-1'); caso você não queria um limite de memória.

Comment: Vlw Fernando pela dica. Mas na prática isso não seria possível com o código rodando em um servidor, pois não teria acesso as diretivas do php.ini...

Comment: Olá, você precisa desse array para algum tratamento de dados futuro ou apenas para imprimir na tela como está no código de exemplo?

Comment: Nesse caso o array vai ser impresso na tela e em seguida ficará disponível para aplicação de uma série de filtros

Comment: Você tem acesso a banco de dados, para poder salvar esses dados do array? Porque se fosse só para impressão em tela, eu teria uma solução bem simples, mas tendo de manipular dados, é necessário bd

Comment: David é aí a minha dúvida. Essa função pode gerar literalmente milhões de índices dentro de uma array. Depois de gerado todas as combinações únicas, aplica-se filtros que irão reduzir significativamente esses índices para então serem salvos pelo usuário no BD

Comment: Entendi. O processo de filtragem pode ser feita durante a geração? Diminuindo assim o array?

Comment: Infelizmente não vi essa possibilidade. Isso pq iria gerar uma demora maior ainda no retorno da função. Por isso optei pela aplicação dos filtros após a geração do array.

Comment: Essa sua recursão sempre tenderá a consumir toda a memoria disponivel. Seria melhor você tentar alguma técnica de [programação dinamica](http://www.vidageek.net/2008/02/11/programacao-dinamica) para reduzir tanto o tempo de exeução (que imagino ser enorme) quanto o consumo de memoria.

Comment: Esse problema conseguiu ser resolvido? Estou com o mesmo problema ao consumir mensagens do RbbitMQ. Chega um momento que dá esse mesmo erro